# Using the Modulus operator to wrap around in Reverse order

Tags: c++

I normally use modulus when I want to wrap around a number i.e.

`current = (current + 1) % list.size()`

In a loop this would go from `0,1,...,list.size()-1` before wrapping around and going back to 0. I was wondering if there was a way to do this in reverse, that is a way that I can go from `list.size()-1, list.size()-2,list.size()-3,...,2,1,0` before wrapping around to list.size()-1 again?

Comment: For the reverse case, it would be enough to test the value against zero (e.g. using a ternary operator: `current = current == 0 ? list.size() - 1 : current - 1;`). No modulus operation needed.

Comment: Are you using unsigneds? Perhaps binary/boolean filers can work.

Comment: If `current` is initialised to `list.size() - 1` then `current = (current - 1)%list.size()` will do it.

Comment: @Peter That can be problematic (`-1 % list.size()` will not give you what you expect). Use `(current + list.size() - 1) % list.size()` instead.

Comment: Would a [mcve] settle it?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - Depends on the type of `current`.   If it is an unsigned type (which is what `list.size()` returns, assuming `list` is an instance of a standard container) it will give the required result.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Im using signed.

Comment: @kars Ok, and which version of C++ are you using?

Comment: @TedLyngmo C++17

Comment: @Peter `0xFFFFFFFF % N` (for 32 bit values) will not be `N - 1` unless N is a power of 2.

Comment: @kars Ok, then add a [tag:language-lawyer] tag to the question an you'll probably get a suitable answer soon.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm This worked, thanks a lot.